# jQuery Multiple 'or' Selectors

Tags: jquery

Is there a way in jQuery to create a selector that has multiple variables in it. I don't want the function to run on all the variables...just something like this:

```
var class1 = '.class1';
var class2 = '.class2';
var class3 = '.class3';

if ($(class1 OR class2 OR class3).is(':visible')) {
    do something;
});
```

So the selector should check if class1 is visible, or class2, or class3, etc etc.

Hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(class1 + ', '+ class2 + ', '+ class3).is(':visible');
```

Comment: Aghh, okay. I was missing the double `+` in my middle class. I thought this was the way...thanks!

Comment: Don't forget the `.` in front of each class name!

Comment: @BradKoch `class1` is a variable if you see the question

Answer (score 0):

Try it like:

```
if($(class1 + ", "+ class2 + ", "+ class3).is(':visible')){
    // do siomething;
}
```